# A simple ordinary equation?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

How to solve the following ordinary equation?
$$-\frac{d^2f(x)}{dx^2}+a f(x)^2=0,$$
where $a>0\in\mathbb{R}$.

Does anybody know of this equation?

Comment: Looks like this has something to do with the Weierstrass p function (http://www.wolframalpha.com/widgets/view.jsp?id=e602dcdecb1843943960b5197efd3f2a). Where the solution is given by $f(x)=\sqrt[3]{\frac6{a}}\wp\left(\sqrt[3]{\frac6{a}}(x+c_1;0,c_2)\right)$

Comment: As usual multiply with $2f'(x)$ and integrate to $-(f'(x))^2+\frac{2a}3f(x)^3=C$. Then proceed with separation to reduce to a normal real integral.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will expand on LutzL's comment, and I will rewrite: $y=f(x)$:
$$-y''+ay^2=0.$$

Use the *integrating factor* $2y'$, multiplying it by every term to get:
$$-2y'y''+2ay'y^2=0.$$

Recognize that this is equivalent to:
$$\frac{d}{dx}\left((y')^2 + \frac{2a}{3}y^3\right)=0$$
by the chain rule. If a derivative is zero, then the function itself is constant, i.e.:
$$(y')^2+\frac{2a}{3}y^3=c.$$

As LutzL mentioned, this is indeed separable; rearranging gives:
$$ \frac{dy}{\pm\sqrt{c-\frac{2a}{3}y^3}}=dx $$
which you must now integrate. Mathematica readily does so, but as mrtaurho noted elliptic functions are involved.